# TensorFlow compiler tests fail

Tags: python, tensorflow

While running 'compiler' tests in TensorFlow(//tensorflow/compiler/tests/...), the tests fail with error:

```
ImportError: No module named backports
```

I tried to install `backports` using pip install but get below error:

```
pip install backports:
          Collecting backports
          Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement backports (from versions: )
          No matching distribution found for backports
```

Has anyone faced same error?
Using python 2.7 and Pip version 8.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

While going through the stack trace of failure, realized that `from backports import weakref` was logged before `ImportError: No module named backports`.

`pip install backports.weakref` resolved the error.